# Django 1.4 - bulk_create with a list

Tags: python, django

I have a list, which I would like to bulk_create entries for in the database.

How can I do this without looping through the list, which I presume, would take away the point of bulk_create.

For example:

Instead of...

```
for x in list:
    bulk_create...
```

How could I...

```
bulk_create for the entire list at once in an efficient manner
```

List contains:

```
list = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
```

It's simply a list of id's, not in the form that's ready to fed directly into bulk_create (not formatted with the entry fields). However, I suppose it would be possible to modify the list before passing it into bulk_create.

Comment: I don't understand. You want to create a list of objects with explicit id's as opposed to letting them auto-incriment? Is that what you are after?

Comment: @jdi I will alter example and try to give a more concrete example.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`bulk_create` takes a list of objects as a single arg, in a single call. What you are doing in your example would be the same as looping and doing `create()`

Referencing: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create

```
aList = [
    Entry(headline="Django 1.0 Released"),
    Entry(headline="Django 1.1 Announced"),
    Entry(headline="Breaking: Django is awesome")
]
Entry.objects.bulk_create(aList)
```

`aList` refers to a list of objects that you already have instantiated and need to create in bulk with one query. If for instance you didn't already have that list of unsaved instances, and you had a list of values, you could then create your list with something like:

```
values = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
# a list of unsaved Entry model instances
aList = [Entry(headline=val) for val in values]
```

Or maybe you have a list of raw dictionary values that map to the model:

```
values = [{headline="abc"}, {headline="def"}, {headline="ghi"}]
aList = [Entry(**vals) for vals in values]
```

Comment: This would still require me to manually put in the arguments in 'aList'. Can you think of any ways to skip this? I already have a list. I suppose I **COULD** convert it to a list of strings each with exactly what you listed in aList?

Comment: @thong: I think you might be missing the point. If you already have a list of objects, just pass that list to `bulk_create` once. This example is showing what a list would contain for you to pass it. If you are still confused about this part, can you update your question to show what is in the list that you already have?

Comment: the list isn't in the format of your aList. i'll try editing altering the list to see if that works.

Comment: @thong: I just updated the values list to match your example. Does that explain it?

Comment: YES! Thanks. I apologize as my less than concrete example must have been confusing at first.

Comment: @thong: Ya I think you might have just been missing the connection between the value list I was referring to, and your own. You already had the list of data. You just needed to map it to unsaved objects.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11543/discussion-between-thong-and-jdi)

Comment: @jdi what if we have list of tuples? Let's say [(1,2,3), (4,5,6), ...]. How to insert in this case?

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> Entry.objects.bulk_create([
...     Entry(headline="Django 1.0 Released"),
...     Entry(headline="Django 1.1 Announced"),
...     Entry(headline="Breaking: Django is awesome")
... ])
```

You're passing the ORM a list of instantiated objects in a list. Using this, and supposing that orig_list is a list of dictionaries,

```
>>> my_objects = [MyObject(a=x['a'], b=x['b']) for x in orig_list]
>>> MyObject.objects.bulk_create(my_objects)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, and the point of bulk_create is to hit database only once, no matter how many you are creating. That's why we consider it to be efficient.

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 10)

a = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4']

Entry.objects.bulk_create([Entry(name=x) for x in a])
```

---Edit---

Say you have a Model like this, in your models.py:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
```

And you have a list like this (directly copied from your question):

```
list = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
```

Simply one line:

```
Entry.objects.bulk_create([Entry(id=x) for x in list])
```

Comment: This would still require me to manually put in the arguments in list a. Can you think of any ways to skip this?

Comment: @thong I guess you overlooked part of my answer. list a here is just for demonstration purpose, no need to "manually put in". See edit.

Comment: thanks! i'm rather new to programming so i didn't get it until the edit.